# Would this code waste resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am using gridview to select multiple records and then play loop over it to individually send each record ID to database and update it but I don't find it very good way to implement because it opens and close connection each time so what is the good way ?

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in grdViewLastHearingDates.Rows)
    {
        int CaseHearingID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Text);
        CheckBox chkBox = r.FindControl("chkBoxIsConveyed") as CheckBox;

        TextBox txtboxConvenienceRemarks = r.FindControl("txtBoxConvenienceRemarks") as TextBox;
        string ConvenienceRemarks = txtboxConvenienceRemarks.Text;

        MngCaseHearings.UpdateCasesIsConveyed(CaseHearingID, ConvenienceRemarks, chkBox.Checked);
    }
```

MngCaseHearings.UpdateCasesIsConveyed sends and executes this code every time for updating each ID. Please review and give suggestions

```
    public Boolean UpdateCasesIsConveyed(int CaseHearingID, string ConvenienceRemarks, bool IsConveyed)
    {

        try
        {
            SqlCommand SqlCom = new SqlCommand("UpdateCasesIsConveyed", DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection());
            SqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pk_CaseHearings_ID ", CaseHearingID);
            SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsConveyed", IsConveyed);
            SqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConvenienceRemarks", ConvenienceRemarks);

            SqlParameter SqlParamReturnStatus = new SqlParameter("@ReturnStatus", SqlDbType.Bit);
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(SqlParamReturnStatus);
            SqlParamReturnStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlParameter SqlParamReturnStatusMessage = new SqlParameter("@ReturnStatusMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
            SqlCom.Parameters.Add(SqlParamReturnStatusMessage);
            SqlParamReturnStatusMessage.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            SqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string ReturnStatusMessage = Convert.ToString(SqlParamReturnStatusMessage);
            Boolean ReturnStatus = Convert.ToBoolean(SqlParamReturnStatus.Value);

            return ReturnStatus;
        }
 catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }

            finally 
            {
                DatabaseConnection.CloseConnection();
            }
```

this would waste the resources so if any good work around ?

Comment: What is `DatabaseConnection`?

Comment: A class object that calls a static method to open connection to data Base

Answer (score 0):

Since the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects both implement `IDisposable` you should probably dispose of them when you're done.  The simplest way would be via the `using` statement:

```
using (var conn = DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection())
using (var SqlCom = new SqlCommand("UpdateCasesIsConveyed", conn))
{
    // setup and execute the SP, can return from in here
}
```

This will ensure that the resources used by the objects are properly closed as soon as you are done.  While this isn't strictly necessary - the `Dispose` method will be called when the garbage collector destroys the objects - it will ensure that you aren't holding open the database objects any longer than necessary.  Depending on how often this is called you can end up with resource shortages on the SQL server, excessive handle usage, etc.

In general anything that implements `IDisposable` should be disposed as soon as practical.

---

(Sorry, missed the loop part of the question)

This type of create/destroy cycle is fine for single operations, but becomes wasteful when used to update a lot of records.  I would put the loop in the middle of the code rather than repeatedly calling this code from outside.

I would create a record class or struct that holds the SP parameters and pass an `IEnumerable` of that record class to your update method.  This way you can do the setup once, process all of the updates, then tear down the database objects after all of the changes have been made.  Throw a transaction in too so you can undo it all if one of the records fails.

Something like:

```
public struct UpdateCaseConveyanceRec
{
    public int CaseHearingID;
    public string ConvenienceRemarks;
    public bool IsConveyed;
}

public bool UpdateCasesIsConveyed(IEnumerable<UpdateCaseConveyanceRec> uopdates)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = DatabaseConnection.OpenConnection())
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UpdateCasesIsConveyed", conn))
    using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction("UpdateCasesIsConveyed"))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        var pID = cmd.Parameters.Add("@pk_CaseHearings_ID", SqlDbType.Int);
        var pConveyed = cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsConveyed", SqlDbType.Bit);
        var pRemarks = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ConvenienceRemarks", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);

        var retStatus = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnStatus", SqlDbType.Bit);
        retStatus.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        var retStatusMsg = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnStatusMessage", SqlDbType.VarChar, -1);
        retStatusMsg.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        try
        {
            foreach (var row in updates)
            {
                pID.Value = row.CaseHearingID;
                pConveyed.Value = row.IsConveyed;
                pRemarks.Value = row.ConvenienceRemarks;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (!Convert.ToBoolean(retStatus))
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch ()
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

You can then feed that with a LINQ to Objects query:

```
var source = 
    from r in grdViewLastHearingDates.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>()
    select new UpdateCaseConveyanceRec
    {
        CaseHearingID = Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[0].Text),
        ConvenienceRemarks = (r.FindControl("txtBoxConvenienceRemarks") as TextBox).Text;
        IsConveyed = (r.FindControl("chkBoxIsConveyed") as CheckBox).Checked
    };

bool updated = UpdateCasesIsConveyed(source);
```

Comment: See my code goes throw gridview and sending each row to the database which then targets Update query.so in this case what should I go with ?